# What does barren eyes mean?

Tags: meaning, metaphors

https://www.google.ca/books/edition/Moorish_Poetry/qEo7AAAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22barren+eyes%22+poem&pg=PA73&printsec=frontcover

> Will they not believe my sighs
>
> Rather than my barren eyes,
>
> As, when laments the dove,
>
> They say, 'He sings of love'?

Is it a metaphorical use for:

> 3. Lacking vegetation, especially useful vegetation: barren tundra.

Because it synonymous to "empty", but it's meaningless here unless it's used as a metaphor.

Comment: It is a poem. Metaphor should be your *first* guess, not your last.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Barren eyes" is not a special well-known phrase or idiom - the words mean what they say, but figuratively since the context is artistic--poems are a work of art by definition.

Eyes are considered the window to the soul/spirit, and "empty eyes" would mean one's eyes look like they are drained of soul or spirit.  The fact that "barren" also is often used to talk about a piece of land's inability to grow vegetation is likely an additional meaning leveraged in the metaphor - i.e. "the eyes look like nothing positive can grow within."

Looking at the meanings of words in poems in this level of detail is an interesting way to fully understand a poem and appreciate the depth of the impression that the writer was trying to create.

Answer (score 0):

The previous verse says *If my tears desert me*, so presumably his 'barren eyes' are unable to weep.

Answer (score 0):

The title of this poem is "Love's Evidence", and the stanza that precedes this quote is:

> If my tears desert me, why
> Do they slyly wink, and cry
> 'He has consoled him', or
> 'He did not love before'?

The author's eyes are "barren" in the sense that they do not *produce* tears. He complains that others take his lack of tears as evidence of a lack of love.